# Secure way to save sensitive data locally?

Tags: ios, swift, security, save

I am wondering what is the best way to save some sensitive data locally on iPhone?

For example, in a game, the amount of gems the user has (note that gems can be bought with real money). I want the data to be stored locally, in order for user to have access to gems, without being connected to the internet, in case he wants to spend them on lives, skins, etc.

At the moment I save the sensitive information in a NSObject class. I convert it to a Data object using an AES-256 encryption and then save it in the document directory with the help of [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift) framework.

Is there a more secure and better way to save the data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730425/what-is-the-best-way-to-secure-users-data-saved-locally-in-app-and-how-to-test.

Comment: They talk there about data such as login credentials. I want to save the properties to an entire custom class e.g : dictionary, array, string, float, int, bool, etc.

Comment: If you convert it to a `Data` object then why can't you use any of the other recommended methods in @MartinR's link?